# Samba share shows wrong disk free space

Tags: debian, networking, samba

I have a virtual machine that I use for a samba share at home. It stores the data on a shared folder from the host machine. Both on the host and guest machines, the total and available space for this specific (and the others) drive show up correctly. Host and Guest machines are running Debian 11.

However, when I try to copy files to the samba share from my laptop, it says there's only 16GB free (vs 1.4TB actually free) and I am forced to use FTP connection. Laptop is running Ubuntu 20.

All that I could try was what I found on stackechange that mentioned adding those two lines to the configuration

```
   dfree command = /usr/local/samba/bin/dfree
   allocation roundup size = 4096
```

Which I did, but without success.

Below is my smb.conf file, if needed.

```
#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# errors. 

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

   dfree command = /usr/local/samba/bin/dfree
   allocation roundup size = 4096
## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = WORKGROUP

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
   interfaces = enp0s9

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine iss: cannot access '/usr/local/samba/bin': No such file or directory
```

root@GC01fileSRVR:~$

```
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

# We want Samba to only log to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd}.
# Append syslog@1 if you want important messages to be sent to syslog too.
   logging = file

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller". 
#
# Most people will want "standalone server" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
   server role = standalone server

   obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
   unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
   pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
   map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
# classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set 
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap config * :              backend = tdb
;   idmap config * :              range   = 3000-7999
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : backend = tdb
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : range   = 100000-999999
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 means that usershare is disabled.
#   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
   usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

[MediaServer]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
   path = /media
   guest ok = no
   read only = no
   create mask = 0600
   directory mask = 0700
   security = user
   encrypt passwords = yes
```

Running

```
ls /usr/local/samba/bin
```

returns

```
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/samba/bin': No such file or directory
```

Running

```
whereis samba
```

returns

```
samba: /usr/sbin/samba /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba /etc/samba /usr/share/samba /usr/share/man/man7/samba.7.gz /usr/share/man/man8/samba.8.gz
```

Some logs:

```
[2021/11/21 15:21:23.198342,  2] ../../source3/smbd/reply.c:747(reply_special)
  netbios connect: local=192.168.1.159 remote=gc01pc, name type = 0
```

Comment: Do you have `/usr/local/samba/bin/dfree`? I'd say it would seem unlikely

Comment: `-bash: cd: /usr/local/samba/bin/dfree: No such file or directory` does not exist, should I just `touch` it?

Comment: Don't try to change to it as a directory; it's a file so that action can't ever work. Use `ls /usr/local/samba/bin` and report back what's in the directory, or the error message. Edit your question to include the results, please.

Comment: this directory does not exist

Comment: Ok. Thanks for checking. That means your suggestion to use `dfree` could not have done anything. What's the exact version of Samba that you've got installed?

Comment: Version 4.9.5-Debian

Comment: I have just upgraded to Version 4.13.13-Debian - couldn't do a worse mistake, now smb is not even working at all anymore. I can't see folders from my laptop.

Comment: If you look in the log files, Samba is probably complaining about `winbind` being missing. It's now a required dependency - just install and run it.

Comment: Still the same error: "Unable to access location - Failed to retreive share list from server: invalid argument.

Comment: You need to look in the server logs. That's where the most informative messages will be

Comment: I added log level to 3 and this is the result... not very telling IMHO

Comment: Ok first problem solved, just needed to add "server min protocol = NT1" to smb,conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
The samba share was pointing at /media that contained two virtualbox shared folders on two different drives, therefore samba could not calculate how much space was left in one drive and in the other drive.